# OOP in JavaScript is so confusing, ES6 is great but not well supported, what to do?

Tags: javascript, oop

I just watched [The Definitive Guide to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://youtu.be/PMfcsYzj-9M). I will never learn how to do OOP in classical way. It mentioned the new spec (ES6). But as far as I know it is [not well supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Is there any workaround to make OOP easier in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use babel.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout `TypeScript`. It's awesome language - a javascript superset and it compiles to pure Javascript which you can run everywhere.

Any JS code is still valid TS code. What TS gives you is a OO approach, type checking, static analysis and new features. When you write code you can immediately start using features from ES6/7 or even ES8 and compile it to ES5 - most supported JS version.

More info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: And not to forget, Angular 2 uses TypeScript, so it will be easier to get started with that as well :)

Comment: it is great to see good solutions. Now I am wondering which one to go for, ES6+babel or TypeScript!

Comment: You can go with Typescript, compile it to ES6, and then for some older browsers compile it via Babel to lower ES versions. What TypeScript truly gives you is TypeChecking and some ES7/ES8 features today ;)

Comment: Thanks @PolishDeveloper. This website is very cool. I am so glad to find very good answers. I cannot upvote your answer yet though.

Comment: You're welcome. Typescript is JS future. We're using it in commercial projects and it helped us a lot. It's still a new technology but community is pretty big, there are many TS fans on StackOverflow. You might encounter some troubles, struggle to write your own typings but it is really worth it. Once you dive into TypeScript you will not want to write pure JS any more.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it is very confusing. But you are lucky to join the community now. [Babel.js](http://babeljs.io) will make your job very easy. If you are not familiar with JavaScript tooling, I recommend you to install [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) and [find the generator](http://yeoman.io/generators/) that you like for your project. Most of the famous framework/libraries's generators have Babel prebuilt into them. If you are familiar with docker, run [yeoman container](https://hub.docker.com/r/aahoo/yeoman/) to get started with one line of code!

Edit:
You can try [generator-webapp container](https://hub.docker.com/r/aahoo/yeoman-webapp/builds/) to get started.

Comment: I got it working with docker. Which generator is good for a newbie to front-end?

Comment: That was sorcery! I am already running the webapp with everything installed. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

es6's classical interface is lexiconal meaning that short of the semantics(syntax) its resulting structure is the same as using the prototypical lexicon.

There are libraries such as [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) that will take ES6's lexicon and convert to the more supported prototyped source.