# is javascript prototype with closure a good thing in terms of good practice

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, prototype

I'm trying to learn javascript for a few weeks (node.js). I have some provious knowledge of .NET, and that turns out to be a bad thing.
My understanding of javascript in general is that:

- everything should be put in functions, we can think of them as
  classes, but not call them that way
- functions (methods) should always be put in a prototype, a prototype is a something like a shared function for every instance of our "class", that is - instatiated once for all of them
- closures are some good thing, they hide private methods, they also seem to last in memory until unknown moment, holding vars

That was written just so you get my current understanding of JS, but the actual question is below: I have some code, hopefully a closure in a prototype, and thus - written in my weak undestanding close to how javascript was intended to be used. So,

1. is javascript prototype with closure a good thing in terms of
   good practice, if it is, is this code good example of that?
2. why whould I want to have "return this" in myclass constructor?
3. and finaly - are parts of code no1 and no2 the same thing?

```js
function createFunctionWithClosure() { // number, and a gensym method that produces unique strings
    var prefix = '';
    var seq = 0;
    return {
      set_prefix(p) {
          prefix = String(p);
        },
        set_seq: function(s) {
          seq = s;
        },
        get_unique: function() {
          var result = prefix + seq;
          seq += 1;
          return result;
        }
    };
  }

//example no1
function myclass_t() {
  //why some examples have
  return this
}
myclass_t.prototype = createFunctionWithClosure();
var myclass = new myclass_t()
myclass.set_prefix('no1--->')
myclass.set_seq(100)
console.log(myclass.get_unique()) //100
console.log(myclass.get_unique()) //101...

//example no2
var myvar = createFunctionWithClosure();
myvar.set_prefix('no2-->')
myvar.set_seq(1000);
myvar.get_unique()
myvar.get_unique()
console.log(myvar.get_unique()) //1002
console.log(myvar.get_unique()) //1003
```

I did try to google a lot of that, but some of informations are (judging by some recent comments) a bit outdated, and possibly not valid any more like for example [this question about perfomance of closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564238/object-oriented-javascript-with-prototypes-vs-closures)

Comment: Take a look at [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for alternative syntax to create classes. It's more similar to C#'s than the one you are currently using. Note that it is pretty new, it's not yet available everywhere.

Comment: I voted to close this question as opinion based.  There doesn't appear to be a problem to be solved here, rather a question about the perceived validity of implementing language logic in a certain way, which can never have a single answer that is correct in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

#### #1 is javascript prototype with closure a good thing in terms of good practice, if it is, is this code good example of that?

A closure is a function where its own scope is referencing members from other scopes:

```
// "x" is being referenced on the inline function's scope
var x = "hello world";
var func = function() {
   console.log(x);
};
```

Whether is a good idea or not, it'll depend on project's requirements... I would say that there're few cases where I would go this route.

#### #2 why whould I want to have "return this" in myclass constructor?

Because of some corner case. If you're developing a [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) you might want to return `this`, and you would do it if the whole function isn't being called from the object where it was declared.

For example:

```
var obj = {
    doStuff: function() {
       return this;
    }

    doStuff2: function() {
       return this;
    }
};

// This is a fluent interface
obj.doStuff().doStuff2();
```

In a *constructor function* returning `this` is useless unless you want to call the whole constructor function as a *regular function* too:

```
var func = function() {
    return this;
};

// The whole "return this" won't have any effect
// on this case
var instance = new func();

// With Function.prototype.call, the first parameter
// defines "this" within the scope of the called function.
// That is, it'll return the object with a text property...
var result = func.call({ text: "hello world" });
```

#### #3 and finaly - are parts of code no1 and no2 the same thing?

No.

Your first sample shows a constructor function where its prototype is the object returned by the [*factory function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

In the other hand, your second sample uses the whole factory function to set its returned object to the whole variable.

Comment: I think, you ware wrong on #1. There seems to be obviously a closure: you have two functions createFunctionWithClosure` (outer) and `get_unique` (inner). And `get_unique` references `prefix` and `seq` which belong to the outer/enclosing function. From my perspective, that is a closure. And the pattern in use is some derived `revealing module` - not the original with an IIFE, but more of a constructor function.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Thanks for noticing it... I've dropped the part of "no, it's not a closure".

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think that what you actually need is to understand the basics of how the prototypal inheritance works in javascript.

Here is a [good video and a live playground](http://www.objectplayground.com/) and [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) is also a good source of information.

Once you understand these things, you may feel like it is a "hackish" way to do things and you whether will need to accept this or move to ES6 or some compile-to-javascript language like TypeScript, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068150/oop-in-javascript-is-so-confusing-es6-is-great-but-not-well-supported-what-to) for more information about this.

Comment: Boris Serebov, yes, not the answer, but the video was very explanatory, and I really needed something like that! As for the TypeScript, I will take a look. Thank you!